# Dropping off your resume in person for a job that does not exist

Tags: resume, job-search

In another question titled "Personally Handing a Resume to an Employer", the consensus was follow the correct procedure which normally means do it online. If however the job does not exist there is no clear procedure to follow. In this situation is handing a resume in person an effective way of making your case for future employment, if not, what other methods could be more effective and why?

Comment: Out of interest why was this on-hold yet the original question is almost identical in spirit and is not on-hold, indeed has great support from the community. The reason given for being on-hold is a bit vague, almost all questions on this SE can be classified as "advice on what to do".

Comment: Cold-calling for jobs (except maybe restaurants and retail) was over 25 years ago. Figure out who might be hiring and get an introduction on Linked-In or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is also not advisable. Because there is no telling whether anyone you would need to talk to about this would even be available you might make the trip in vein and even if you can talk to someone, you might come at a very inconvenient time four them. That does not leave a good impression, which is what you are trying to accomplish.

Instead, write an email conveying your enthusiasm and idea (and how this would benefit them and not just you) , attach your resume and let them deal with your inquiry at their own convenience. Add that you'd be happy to discuss this on the phone or in person, if you want.

Yes, they might never answer, but this at least won't leave them with a bad impression.

Comment: This is not actually about me, detailing how it would benefit the company is a great suggestion which I shall pass along.

Answer (score 4):

Catching people by surprise, putting them on the spot and getting in their faces as a way to make friends and influence people so that you can get hired - that's definitely inadvisable unless you have a persona as a sales person who excels at cold calling. Or you want to learn how to be a sales person who excels at cold calling.

I look at sales people who excel at cold calling me with a mixture of fear, admiration and loathing :) - fear because I don't know them and I don't expect them and here they are, right in my face. Admiration for having the sheer guts to get in my home ground as uninvited, total strangers who know that the first three words they say to the receptionist could send them packing. And loathing because even if they got shot through the head, they WILL be back. I don't think that there too many of these sales people any more.

If you show up uninvited, there is a 95+% probability that you will be treated as an interloper. And that's assuming that you make it to the receptionist's desk. More likely, you won't make it past building security if they have building security, so you won't even get to the receptionist's desk.

Comment: The person is quite friendly, I would imagine their approach would be to chat to HR and ask what they are looking for in engineering graduates. Which is to say the tone would be similar to a university careers expo. Then ask if they have any unskilled positions so he could start contributing to the company / better understand engineering work environments. Sounds like email would be the way to go however, or perhaps a university careers day maybe?

Comment: @User university careers days, online and off-line job fairs, in my case - sideline and off-line conversations at computer meetups, conferences - I love Pycon, etc. Meet people, talk to them long enough to get their contact info, pick their brains after the event is over. The more informal the setting, the better the chances for the new professional to network successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping off your resume when a job doesn't exist will not generally work for many companies because they need a job opening to attach the resume to. Many times they flush all the old resumes from there system after a few months under the assumption they are outdated or out of the market, though some do keep electronic ones longer a a source of contact information.

Unless the company is small there is no way to know that HR or the relevant hiring manger will be at that location. If that isn't the right place it is unlikely that the resume will end up in the right place.

You will have better luck with a contact that works there or somebody you meet at a university event.